# Rails: saving a record if it has a unique value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm probably searching for the wrong thing here, and I'm dumb so let me explain.

I have a rake task that is polling a web service every 10 minutes via cron, the response is JSON.

For each of the items in the response I need to create a record only if a certain column has a unique value, in this case thats a hash.

Here's the meat of the task:

```
response.parsed_response['items'].each do |item|
  Item.create({
    :item_hash => item['item_hash']
  })
end
```

The thing is that I only want to do this if the `hash` value is unique, is this rudimentary behavior or am I missing some obvious method in ActiveRecord?

Comment: What do you mean by unique? Do you mean relative to other item_hash values in your in DB? Can you also include any validations that you have in your Item class?

Comment: Well its not really saving from a form so are validations the right way to go? by Unique I mean if any other `Item` record has the same `item_hash` value (which is just a string actually in my case), then don't save it.

Comment: As long as the validations exist in AR it doesn't matter where the data is coming from, they will still fire if one is not satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find_or_create`

```
Item.find_or_create_by_item_hash(item['item_hash'])
```

If the data already exists Item is not created.

If you are processing lot of records I would use the following approach:

```
all_hashes = response.parsed_response['items'].map{|item| item['item_hash']}
new_hashes = all_hashes - Item.all(:select => :item_hash, 
               :conditions => {:item_hash => all_hashes}).map(&:item_hash)
Item.create(new_hashes.map{|hash| {:item_hash => hash}})
```

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: Rails 3+ way to do this is `Item.where(item: item['item_hash']).first_or_create`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the Railsy route, then ActiveRecord validations are the way to go, like Pan Thomakos suggested.  There's nothing wrong with using ActiveRecord with non-form data; AR doesn't know (or care) where the data comes from.

There's an SQL route, too:  You can pair a unique index with `INSERT IGNORE`, and your values will only be inserted if they're unique.  If you need to know whether the insert succeeded, you can kill the `IGNORE` and use a rescue block (you might also be able to get the "# rows changed" value back from MySQL, but I'm not sure how to do this in Rails).

Hope this helps!